# Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type while rebuilding

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I am using Room database and Live data. While rebuilding the project, I am getting error. I am getting the error for following code:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM book_table")
LiveData<List<Book>> getBooks();
```

Error Log:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (LiveData<List<Book>>)
```

Room.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "book_table", foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Category.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "category_id", onDelete = CASCADE))
public class Book extends BaseObservable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "book_name")
    private String name;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "book_price")
    private double price;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id")
    private int categoryId;

    public Book(String name, double price, int categoryId) {
        setName(name);
        setPrice(price);
        setCategoryId(categoryId);
    }

    @Bindable
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.id);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
    }

    @Bindable
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.price);
    }

    @Bindable
    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.categoryId);
    }
}
```

using data binding in this as well. Two tables are there in this project. Category and Book.

Comment: Put the error log.

Comment: Check now, I have edited the question.

Comment: Which Library version ypu are using.?

Comment: Also try to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: for room I am using 2.2.0-alpha02.

Comment: tried cleaning and rebuilding , not working.

Comment: Can you show your class `Book.java`?

Comment: @tahsinRupam I have added Book.java. Check

Comment: Try  to use stable or beta version

Comment: Which is the latest stable version?

Comment: I migrated the whole project to androidx and the bug got fixed.